# Usando el scroll horizontal de jquery datatables la tabla se daña

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

Tengo un problema al momento de usar el plugin jquery datatables con el scroll horizontal.

Active el scroll horizontal para las ocasiones en que la tabla es mas grande que el contenedor y de esta manera se mantengan las proporciones justas, sin embargo en un tabla que funcionaba correctamente sin el scroll, se daño al activar el scroll en el eje horizontal.

Para activar el scroll uso las siguiente lineas de código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tblemp').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true
    } );
} );
```

**Tabla con el problema**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true
    } );
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Problema</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
      <table id="example">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="tg-031e">Cedula</th>
          <th class="tg-031e">Nombres</th>
          <th class="tg-yw4l">Modalidad</th>
          <th class="tg-yw4l">Email</th>
          <th class="tg-yw4l">Actualizar</th>
          <th class="tg-yw4l">Eliminar</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-031e">0702110453</td>
          <td class="tg-031e">SAQUINAULA RODRIGO PATRICIO</td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l">nombramiento</td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l">X</td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l">O</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-031e">0702471806</td>
          <td class="tg-031e">JIMENEZ FEIJOO GRACIELA ESPERANZA</td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l">nombramiento</td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l">gjimenez@prefecturaloja.gob.ec</td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l">X</td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l">O</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
          <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

A continuación la tabla normal, y la tabla deformada.

**Tabla Normal**
[image: Tabla Normal]

**Tabla Dañada**
[image: Tabla Dañada]

En la tabla deforme se puede ver como las columnas aparecen desfasadas, es decir que la cabecera con concuerda con el cuerpo de tabla.

**¿Qué podría hacer para solucionar este problema?**

**EDIT**

Me he dado cuenta el problema es con pantallas grandes, ajustando el ancho del div a 800px se arregla de alguna manera el problema, pero no es lo que busco, ya que necesito que la tabla se vea en todo el espacio del contenedor.

Con esta linea de css, se arregla pero solo con el ancho 800px

```
div.dataTables_wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución es definir que el estilo `.dataTables_scrollHeadInner` tenga `margin: 0 auto` (para centrar la `table` que contiene los `headers`

**// UPDATE**

Si quieres que ocupe el `100%` del ancho disponible, podrias hacer esto:

- Crear una regla para `#example` que indique `width:100%`.
- Para hacerla `responsive`, podemos hacer un `JS` para detectar el `resize` del navegador y actualizar el tamaño de la `table` ya el `plugin` para `scroll horizontal` establece a la misma un `ancho` en `px`.

Así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "scrollX": true
  });
  
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('#example').css('width', '100%');
    table.draw(true);
  });
});
```

```css
#example {
  width: 100%;
}
.dataTables_scrollHeadInner {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Problema</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
        <table id="example">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="tg-031e">Cedula</th>
              <th class="tg-031e">Nombres</th>
              <th class="tg-yw4l">Modalidad</th>
              <th class="tg-yw4l">Email</th>
              <th class="tg-yw4l">Actualizar</th>
              <th class="tg-yw4l">Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="tg-031e">0702110453</td>
              <td class="tg-031e">SAQUINAULA RODRIGO PATRICIO</td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l">nombramiento</td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l">X</td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l">O</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tg-031e">0702471806</td>
              <td class="tg-031e">JIMENEZ FEIJOO GRACIELA ESPERANZA</td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l">nombramiento</td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l">gjimenez@prefecturaloja.gob.ec</td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l">X</td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l">O</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
              <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Es una opción útil, sin embargo sigue quedando mas pequeño que el contenedor, no se podría hacer algo para usar todo el espacio del contenedor?

Comment: @JuanPinzón, he actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias Marcos, me fue útil tu respuesta.